# Java two-dimensional auto sorting by itself

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've got a really weird thing and no more ideas what it could be. Here is the code:

```
 public static int[][] permutations(int n){
    int amount = 1;
    int[] sourceArray = new int[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        sourceArray[i] = i;
        amount *= i+1;
    }
    permutationArray = new int[amount][n];
    permute(sourceArray, 0);
    for(int i=0; i<permutationArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + " top: " + Arrays.toString(permutationArray[i]));
    }
    return permutationArray;
}

public static void permute(int[] array, int i) {
    if (i == array.length) {
        permutationArray[counter] = array;
        System.out.println(counter + " bottom: " + Arrays.toString(permutationArray[counter]));
        counter++;
        return;
    }
    for (int j = i; j < array.length; j++) {
        swap(array, i, j); 
        permute(array, i + 1); 
        swap(array, i, j);      
    }
}
```

Considering the two-dimensional Array I get following output:

```
0 bottom: [0, 1, 2]
1 bottom: [0, 2, 1]
2 bottom: [1, 0, 2]
3 bottom: [1, 2, 0]
4 bottom: [2, 1, 0]
5 bottom: [2, 0, 1]
0 top: [0, 1, 2]
1 top: [0, 1, 2]
2 top: [0, 1, 2]
3 top: [0, 1, 2]
4 top: [0, 1, 2]
5 top: [0, 1, 2]
```

As we can the sort within the recursively method is different than the other one. What is happen here?

Comment: Arrays are references, so `permutationArray[counter] = array;` does not copy the array, just set up a new reference for it. U should use `System.arraycopy()` to copy arrays...

Comment: You are great! Thanks a lot :-)